# write a scripting language in python

Tags: python, scripting, scripting-language

I'm relatively new to programming, and I would like to write a simple scripting language as an exercise, and to learn a bit. I have experience with Python, C, and Ruby, and would like to learn to write a scripting language in Python. What should be my first step? How should I start?

Comment: when i say very simple, i mean dead simple. think: print, some math, variables

Comment: So If i really get you correct, you want to invent another programming language using Python?

Comment: yep! it's a learning exercise!

Comment: @tekknolagi A simple language core isn't so complex in, he can reuse everything with Python language constructs and data structures. I.e. he doesn't need to implement dictionary, python has already one, etc. If his language doesn't differ from Python very heavily, I think he can be ready in some ten KBytes of code.

Comment: I think at first you should start to write a command interpreter, i.e. which reads in a command file and executes it. Because it is your first language (what extraordinarily meaning has it in this context ;-) ), try to implement the most primitive language as you can only imagine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the first step is to choose a language (or at least *style* of language). An easy one to start with is the style of [Forth](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29), where each "word" in the source code is handled in exactly the same way. This makes lexical analysis and parsing nearly trivial.

Another small language to start with is [Scheme](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29). The parsing is a bit more involved because it involves recursion, but it's still tractable. You can find various examples of Scheme-in-Python around the web, it's been done lots of times.

Comment: i was thinking something in the style of a dumbed down python

Comment: and i'm familiar with recursion

Comment: Python (even dumbed-down Python) is still a reasonably complex language, as far as lexing, parsing, syntax trees, and so on. Both Forth and Scheme spare you from having to write an algebraic expression parser, which is helpful if you're learning the basics of language implementation. (You'll probably end up wanting to write an expression parser at some point anyway, but you don't have to do it first.)

Comment: Okay scheme looks good - where could you point me in terms of a small tutorial?

Comment: Here's a handful of links to get you started: http://norvig.com/lispy.html (<- Norvig has a good tutorial along with the code) https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/pyscheme/ https://github.com/ghewgill/psil http://thinkpython.blogspot.com/2005/02/simple-scheme-interpreter.html

Comment: hey i'm friends with peter! that's actually awesome...

Answer (score 1):

Writing a scripting language will probably exceed 'learn[ing] a bit'. I think it's too much. But if you are serious enough, you might want to start by playing around with [racc](https://github.com/tenderlove/racc) or [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), YACC bindings for ruby and python, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just as a learning exercise, I would recommend reading through this tutorial on [how to make a s*** javascript interpreter in python](http://renesd.blogspot.com/2010/06/lets-make-shit-javascript-interpreter.html). Javascript can be very basic, and it explains things at a very beginner level.

Answer (score 0):

draw out a finite state automata of how your language is going to work, write a syntax analyzer, draw some diagrams. Hack on!

Comment: that's the thing - how would i even start to write a syntax analyzer?